# How to extract file name without file extention using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have tried using this:

```
awk 'END{ var=FILENAME; n=split (var,a,/\//); print basename a[n]}'
```

and it is returning full path.

Does anyone know how to get the result without the extention?

Example: 
`D:\Test\test.tested.txt` --> `test`

using `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo "D:\Test\test.tested.txt" | 
  awk '{n=split($1,a,"\\"); split(a[n],b,"."); print b[1]}'

test
```

for your script

```
... END{n=split(FILENAME,a,"\\"); split(a[n],b,"."); print b[1]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below answer.

awk 'END{ var=FILENAME; n=split (var,a,///); print a[n] }' D:\Test\test.tested.txt | awk -F"." '{print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

The `AWK` code below does what you want:

```
!uniq[FILENAME]++ {
    aux[++k] = FILENAME;
    next;
}
END {
    for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        a = split(aux[i], x, ".");
        print x[1];
    }
}
```

As an one liner:

```
!uniq[FILENAME]++{aux[++k] = FILENAME; next;} END {for(i = 1; i <= k; i++) {a = split(aux[i], x, "."); print x[1];}} files
```

The `next`, at least on my machine, gives a slight faster result than omitting it from the code.

Note: The code above gives you a sorted output according to the order of the files you pass to it, that is, if you give it the files `file01.txt file02.txt data01.txt`, they will be sorted in that same order:

```
file01
file02
data01
```

A shorter version of that same code would be:

```
!filename[FILENAME]++ {
        next;
}
END {
        for(i in filename)
        {
                a = split(i, x, ".");
                print x[1];
        }
}
```

As an one liner:

```
!filename[FILENAME]++ {next;} END {for(i in filename) {a = split(i, x, "."); print x[1];}} files
```

The result is not sorted in any sense. It is up to the user to sort it.